# openapi 3.0 valid minimum and maximum values

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator, codegen

I have below schema definition to represent `commission amount` in my openapi contract.

```
commissionAmount:
  type: number
  minimum: -99999.99
  maximum: 99999.99
```

Generated Code:

```
@Valid
@DecimalMin("-99999.99") @DecimalMax("99999.99") 
public BigDecimal getCommissionAmount() {
  return commAmt;
}
```

The generated code is good and as expected. I just wanted to know are these `-99999.99` and `99999.99` valid values for `minimum` and `maximum`.

The reason for asking this question is it does not check the limit in the fractional part. For example, I expect `12345.678` is invalid , `12345.67` is valid. But it marks both as valid.

I read `@Digits` is used to check for the digit limit of integer and fractional part. How do I tell `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` to annotate `Digits` as well?

Expected Generated Code:

```
@Valid
@Digits(integer = 5, fraction = 2)
@DecimalMin("-99999.99") @DecimalMax("99999.99") 
public BigDecimal getCommissionAmount() {
  return commAmt;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The way to specify this in OpenAPI would be using `multipleOf`:

```yaml
commissionAmount:
  type: number
  minimum: -99999.99
  maximum: 99999.99
  multipleOf: 0.01
```

However, using the OpenAPI Generator **will not produce an annotation** for this. The reason being is that there is no `javax.validation` annotation that can represent `multipleOf` effectively (imagine trying to express `multipleOf: 0.02`- `@Digits` would be insufficient).

However, you can create your own annotation as this user has: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/2192#issuecomment-575132233

With the following annotation and validator:

```java
@Target({METHOD, FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(MultipleOf.List.class)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MultipleOfValidator.class)
public @interface MultipleOf {

    double value();

    String message() default "{error.multipleOf}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

    @Target({ METHOD, FIELD })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {
        MultipleOf[] value();
    }

}
```

```java
public class MultipleOfValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MultipleOf, Number> {

    private double value;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MultipleOf constraintAnnotation) {
        this.value = constraintAnnotation.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Number value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return (value == null) || (value.doubleValue() / this.value) % 1 == 0;
    }

}
```

You would then be able to fork the generator and add your new annotation to the template: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/beanValidationCore.mustache

With a line like this:

```
{{#multipleOf}}@MultipleOf({{multipleOf}}){{/multipleOf}}
```

Comment: Is there any update on this with new versions?