# Set Min and Max values between 0.1 and 0.9 in OpenApi

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator, codegen

I defined **missingRatio** variable in my openApi yaml file as below. Openapi version is **"3.0.0"**

**api.yaml**

```
missingRatio:
  type: number
  format: float
  minimum: 0.1
  maximum: 0.3
  default: 0.2
  multipleOf: 0.1
  description: "Ratio of data to remove for validation"
```

But unfortunately in generated code **min and max values are set to 0**. So when I use, it only accepts **0** as value.

**generated code**

```
  /**
   * Ratio of data to remove for validation
   * minimum: 0
   * maximum: 0
   * @return missingRatio
  **/
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Ratio of data to remove for validation")

  @DecimalMin("0") @DecimalMax("0") 
  public Float getMissingRatio() {
    return missingRatio;
  }
```

How Can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAPI 3.0 valid minimum and maximum values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60808674/113116)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should remove the format: float from your schema. Floating point arithmetic is unreliable. Leave the field as BigDecimal and see if it works.

@DecimalMin and @DecimalMax work for BigDecimals and not float as per documentation

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/DecimalMin.html

Excerpt from Oracle docs:

> Note that `double` and `float` are not supported due to rounding errors (some providers might provide some approximative support).
>
> `null` elements are considered valid.

Comment: Sounds more like a comment than an actual answer. Avoid answers that require further confirmation. See [answer].