# In Swagger CodeGen, how do you specify a field maximum with decimal places?

Tags: openapi, java-11, swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

We're using Java 11 with the following version of Swagger Codegen

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.35</version>
```

I have this in my OpenAPI 3 spec for a particular DTO field,

```
    amount:
      type: number
      format: double
      maximum: 99999999.99
      multipleOf: 0.01
```

Upon running the plugin, the DTO is generated without the decimal places

```
  /**
   * Get amount
   * maximum: 99999999
   * @return amount
  **/
  @Schema(required = true, description = "")
  @NotNull

   @DecimalMax("99999999")   public Double getAmount() {
    return amount;
  }
```

As a result, when I submit a value for my listed maximum, 99999999.99, I get this error

```
"errorMessage": "must be less than or equal to 99999999"
```

What's the proper way in the openAPI spec and Swagger code gen to have a maximum field with decimal places included afterwards?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAPI 3.0 valid minimum and maximum values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60808674/113116)

Comment: I'm already doing that, no?  Also I can't tell what version of SwaggerCode gen that poster is using.  I have posted my version and the generated DTO so not sure if it is a bug in the verision or somethign else I'm doing.

Comment: Did you specify useBeanValidation=true (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7795)? 
like

                            <configOptions>
                                <bigDecimalAsString>true</bigDecimalAsString>
                                <dateLibrary>joda</dateLibrary>
                                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
...
                            </configOptions>

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
amount:
  type: number
  format: double
  exclusiveMaximum: 100000000
  multipleOf: 0.01
```

Comment: "exclusiveMaximum" doesn't seem to be a field supported by Swagger codegen

Answer (score 0):

Try this based on format double (am aware that DTO is not generating decimal), add it within the swagger-codegen-maven-plugin configuration in your pom.xml:

```xml
<configuration>
   <typeMappings>
     <typeMapping>Double=java.math.BigDecimal</typeMapping>
   </typeMappings>
</configuration>
```